# Accessing variables in a class from another class

Tags: c#, class, instance-variables

I have many classes, call them `Class1`, `Class2`, ..., and so on. Each of these classes has two variables, `TestDictionary` and `TestListDictionary`, as follows. Each of these classes also call a method `DoWork()` from another class `OtherClass`, and passes in a string containing the name of the class (`"Class1", "Class2", ...`).

```
public class Class1
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> TestDictionary = ...
    public static ListDictionary TestListDictionary
    ...
    OtherClass.DoWork(GetType().Name);
}
```

I want the function `DoWork` to be able to access the two variables `TestDictionary` and `TestListDictionary`. I thought of doing the following:

```
DoWork(string className)
{
    var newClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className));
    var newDictionary = newClass.TestDictionary;
    var newListDictionary = newClass.TestListDictionary;
    ...
}
```

But I am not able to access `TestDictionary` and `TestListDictionary` (error "cannot resolve symbol 'TestDictionary'/'TestListDictionary').

Say I cannot pass these two variables to the `DoWork` function directly for various reasons. How would I access them?

Edit: I tried removing the `static` keyword and still run into the same error.

Comment: Passing in the name of a class seems like a code smell to me. Using inheritance might be a better way to design this

Comment: I want to be able to access whatever values `TestDictionary` and `TestListDictionary` have in each instance of `Class1`, `Class2`, ... etc.

Comment: I see. I tried removing the `static` keyword but still have the same error.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Which instance of TestDictionary are you trying to access from which class ? How is DoWork() invoked ? To what does 'OtherClass' refers ?

Comment: Each class 1 through n has an instance of TestDictionary. DoWork is a method within OtherClass and is called within each class 1 through n, and needs to reference that class's instance of TestDictionary and TestListDictionary. Does that clear it up?

Comment: What is the purpose of the different classes? Why do you need `Class1` and `Class2`? I think you are abusing `static` members when you actually just need multiple instances of a single class. You should ignore all of the existing answers as they all miss the point completely.

Comment: The different classes are necessary due to different methods in them. I did not include that part of the code since it did not affect accessing variables from each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the *static* member with the `object` of class. You can access the static member with class instead of its instance. Get the type of the class and do not create instance of the type.

**Edit**

You can use `GetField` and `GetValue` to get the static field i.e. `TestDictionary`, Note you have to give ([assembly-qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx)) that include the namespace for the class name passed in `Type.GetType`.

```
var newType  = Type.GetType(className);
```

<strike>var newDictionary = newType.TestDictionary;</strike>

```
var newDictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)newType.GetField("TestDictionary").GetValue(null);
//newDictionary.Add("1","hello");
//Console.WriteLine(Class1.TestDictionary["1"]);
```

Comment: This answers the question on a technicality but I really don't think it gets at the real problem with what the OP is doing. Nor does it explain the problem in a way the OP is likely to understand.

Comment: I don't understand how that works.. Type class doesn't have those static properties.. you need to get values using reflection. `newType.GetField("TestDictionary", BindingFlags.Public |BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);`

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing up the difference! I tried the code you suggested, but still get the error "cannot resolve symbol 'TestDictionary'/'TestListDictionary'". I tried removing the `static` and using the code I originally posted, and still get the same error.

Comment: @user2424607 there was a problem in getting the dictionary as suggested by Selman22. Check my updated answer.

Comment: This answer still completely misses the point, which is that the OP is using *classes with static fields* in place of *objects*.

Comment: @Adil Thank you for your help. I found my primary problem was not having the full assembly name for my class when creating an instance of it. I was able to fix my problems with `var newClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("[namespace]" + className + ", " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.ToString()));`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiert way not using `Reflection` is to create a `Dictionary` containing the collections you want to access. The class name serves as key.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Dictionaries
         = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, ListDictionary> ListDictionaries
         = new Dictionary<string, ListDictionary>();
```

}

Now `Class1` can add its own dictionaries like this:

```
Globals.Dictionaries.Add("Class1", TestDictionary);
Globals.ListDictionaries.Add("Class1", TestListDictionary);
```

And another class can access them with:

```
Globals.Dictionaries[classname].Add(key, value);
int count = Globals.ListDictionaries[classname].Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Class1`, a variable defined as static:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> TestDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
public static string test = "hey!";
```

Can be accessed from another class:

```
var newDictionary = Class1.TestDictionary;
string test = Class1.test;
```

Answer (score 0):

try inheriting the classes like this

```
public abstract class abstractA
    {
        public abstract string  TestDictionary { get; set; }
        public abstract string TestListDictionary { get; set; }
       // public abstract string returnDictionary();
        public void   DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.TestDictionary);
            // do anything with the properties         
        }
    }

    public class classA : abstractA
    {
        public override string TestDictionary { get; set; }
        public override string TestListDictionary { get; set; }
        public classA(string a, string b )
        {
            this.TestDictionary = a;
            this.TestDictionary = b; 
        }

    }
```

I have used string for making it simple. you could use dictionary or any object you want